# Embed YouTube Channel - Full Screen not working, and not auto-HD

Tags: youtube, embed, youtube-channels

two questions really, but hopefully you will allow.

I am trying to embed a YouTube channel using the google widget, which is working apart from two problems:

1/ The full screen icon does not seem to work
2/ When the video plays full screen (by selecting 'Play on YouTube')it is not HD by default

Here is the channel embedded on our site :
[Embedded Channel Example](http://leansoftware.net/en-us/help/excel-database-tasks/introduction.aspx)

Hope you can help